# How can I perform the same action multiple times based on a number selected in a drop down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

How can I generate multiple sets of dropdowns and text type input fields (where one set consists of 3 dropdowns and 1 input type=text), based on number of times it has to be generated is by selecting a number from another dropdown.

my code is this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Add New Detail</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orienta' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style type="text/css">
#main {
    background-color:#0CF;
    width:600px;
    padding:25px 0;
}

#drop_box_set {
    background:#666;
    width:90%;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:25px 0;
}

</style>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
<!--------------------------- CHANGE OPTIONS ON CHILD DROPDOWN SCRIPT ---------------------------->
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

<script type="text/javascript">
function setOptions(chosen, selbox) {

selbox.options.length = 0;
if (chosen == " ") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options above first',' ');
setTimeout(setOptions(' ',document.add_new_customer_form.optthree),5);
}
if (chosen == "1") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('first choice - option one','11');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('first choice - option two','12');
setTimeout(setOptions('11',document.add_new_customer_form.optthree),5);
}
if (chosen == "2") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('second choice - option one','21');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('second choice - option two','22');
setTimeout(setOptions('21',document.add_new_customer_form.optthree),5);
}
if (chosen == "3") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('third choice - option one','31');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('third choice - option two','32');
setTimeout(setOptions('31',document.add_new_customer_form.optthree),5);
}
if (chosen == "11") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('first choice - option one - sub one','111');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('first choice - option one - sub two','112');
}
if (chosen == "12") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('first choice - option two - sub one','121');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('first choice - option two - sub two','122');
}
if (chosen == "21") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('second choice - option one - sub one','211');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('second choice - option one - sub two','212');
}
if (chosen == "22") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('second choice - option two - sub one','221');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('second choice - option two - sub two','222');
}
if (chosen == "31") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('third choice - option one - sub one','311');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('third choice - option one - sub two','312');
}
if (chosen == "32") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('third choice - option two - sub one','321');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('third choice - option two - sub two','322');
}
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div align="center"><!--DIV ALIGNMENT CENTER START-->

<div id="main"><!--DIV MAIN START-->

<form name="add_new_customer_form" method="post" action="">

<label class="description">Number Of Computer Devices : </label>

            <select name="element_19" class="short_select"> 
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                        <option value="01" >01</option>
                        <option value="02" >02</option>
                        <option value="03" >03</option>
                        <option value="04" >04</option>
                        <option value="05" >05</option>
                        <option value="06" >06</option>
                        <option value="07" >07</option>
                        <option value="08" >08</option>
                        <option value="09" >09</option>
                        <option value="10" >10</option>
                        <option value="11" >11</option>
                        <option value="12" >12</option>
                        <option value="13" >13</option>
                        <option value="14" >14</option>
                        <option value="15" >15</option>

        </select>
<div id="drop_box_individual"><!--DIV DROP_BOX_INDIVIDUAL START-->
<label class="description">Device Type : </label>

            <select name="optone" class="element select medium" style="width:200px;" onchange="setOptions(document.add_new_customer_form.optone.options[document.add_new_customer_form.optone.selectedIndex].value,document.add_new_customer_form.opttwo);">
                <option value=" " selected="selected"> </option>
                        <option value="1">First Choice</option>
                        <option value="2">Second Choice</option>
                        <option value="3">Third Choice</option>
            </select>

</div><!--DIV DROP_BOX_INDIVIDUAL ENDS-->

<div id="drop_box_individual"><!--DIV DROP_BOX_INDIVIDUAL START-->
<label class="description">Device Brand : </label>

            <select name="opttwo" class="element select medium" style="width:200px;" onchange="setOptions(document.add_new_customer_form.opttwo.options[document.add_new_customer_form.opttwo.selectedIndex].value,document.add_new_customer_form.optthree);">
                <option value=" " selected="selected"></option>
            </select>
</div><!--DIV DROP_BOX_INDIVIDUAL ENDS-->

<div id="drop_box_individual"><!--DIV DROP_BOX_INDIVIDUAL START-->
<label class="description">Operating System : </label>

            <select name="optthree" class="element select medium" style="width:200px;">
                <option value=" " selected="selected"></option>
            </select>

</div><!--DIV DROP_BOX_INDIVIDUAL ENDS-->

<div id="drop_box_individual"><!--DIV DROP_BOX_INDIVIDUAL START-->
<label class="description">Serial Number : </label>

            <input name="element_10" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/>
</div><!--DIV DROP_BOX_INDIVIDUAL ENDS-->
</form>
</div><!--DIV MAIN ENDS-->
</div><!--DIV ALIGNMENT CENTER ENDS-->

</body>
</html>
```

Also, here is a link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/v5kvX/1/) I came across while searching for a solution.

In this above jsFiddle if one clicks on "add" button it generates a set of 02 dropdowns + 01 type=text input fields and a REMOVE button, in case some one generated more than requirement.

This is what exactly I need, But the difference is that I need it to be a automated process.

What I need is (according to my code):

If 05 is selected from the fist dropdown saying "Number of Computer Devices", it should generate 05 sets of dropboxes and type=text inputs and remove buttons.

It should generate 05 sets, where `01 set = 03 dropdowns + 01 type=text` input field and a remove button if generated more than requiremt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a loop to your code.

Like this

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=button][value=Add]").click(function(e) {
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById('sel').value; i++) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var newDiv = $("<div>").appendTo("#div");
            $("<input>").attr("name", "a").appendTo(newDiv);
            $("<input>").attr("name", "b").appendTo(newDiv);
            $("<select>").attr("name", "c").appendTo(newDiv).append(
            $("<option>").val("0").text("Option 1"), $("<option>").val("1").text("Option 2"));
            $("<select>").attr("name", "d").appendTo(newDiv).append(
            $("<option>").val("0").text("Option 1"), $("<option>").val("1").text("Option 2"));
            $("<button>").text("Remove").appendTo(newDiv).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                newDiv.remove();
            })
        }
    })
})
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <div id="div"></div>
    <select id="sel">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    <input type="button" value="Add" />
</form>
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/bYBPD/

Comment: thnx for suggesting me this solution. i have had a look at that. it is working fine, but one thing i would like to add here is this: Let's say i selected 3 from the list and added - it is generating 3 set of required fields successfully (also i have tried to add 15 as per my requirement and it did it.). but when i click remove it is capable to remove only one. Can you please suggest something for this. Another is we still have to click on ADD button to generate the fields. Can we do it by simply selecting the numbers from drop down (i am having upto 15 at maximum) TO BE CONTINUED.....

Comment: CONTINUED ...   | Or if let's say i added 3 and then i removed 1 out of it, can the selection automatically get back to 2 (as only two sets are left on that page now).

Comment: Thank you very very much for making this happen for me. It's working perfectly fine. S.T.A.R.S to you for this. :) Although the problem is solved but can i expect answers to some more small questions i just have come up with? (if it's fine with you !!)

Comment: alright if i am right here, to insert the data to a mysql database we can assign a new id="xxx" or name="xxx" to or radio/selection/input type=text and/or input type=textarea (actually all of them). Here in my case i am using <input name="xxx" type="whatever"> instead of <input id="xxx" type="whatever">, so as these new generated fields are dynamic {more over one set have 4 fields (2 drop downs and 2 inputs)}. i am not able to understand that how would i know that what is the name="xxx" assigned to which one? This might seems to be a foolish question but i really can't help it.

Comment: instead of creating dynamic form fields with JS, why dont you do it in your server with PHP or ASPX?

Comment: actually i am not able to understand that so let me explain what i have : .php extension saved page starting with a PHP validator script as the form is going to be submitted first to itself so not to loose values in case or errors. Than a js validator script to show the errors right under the relavant field having error. Than the js to change options to another dropdown based on selection made in last dropdown same as in my code above in question. Than a js to autojump so while entering phone number it can auto jump from one to another field {TO BE CNTD.}

Comment: {CNTD...}  |  to insert data so that user just have to enter the phone number and it will take care of jumping. Than this js that you just have provided to me. Finally comes the BODY setup in table format of HTML, a nice look added using CSS. Obviously connection script and close connection script to be able to submit data to database. This is all i can think of right now to explain...

Comment: alright if i am right here, to insert the data to a mysql database we can assign a new id="xxx" or name="xxx" to or radio/selection/input type=text and/or input type=textarea (actually all of them). Here in my case i am using <input name="xxx" type="whatever"> instead of <input id="xxx" type="whatever">, so as these new generated fields are dynamic {more over one set have 4 fields (2 drop downs and 2 inputs)}. i am not able to understand that how would i know that what is the name="xxx" assigned to which one?

Comment: @Harsh wow :o that is a lot of text. it will be very difficult to help you here. you will have to create a test page in your server with all the relevant code that you want help.

Comment: well let me understand you first. Is this that you want me to do : Create a page with only the parts of code where i am facing problems like this one above in the question ??!!?? And is that so that you would like to help ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip: you can replace:

```
> <select name="optone" ... onchange="setOptions(document.add_new_customer_form.optone.options[document.add_new_customer_form.optone.selectedIndex].value,document.add_new_customer_form.opttwo);">
```

with:

```
<select name="optone" ... onchange="setOptions(this.value, this.form.opttwo)">
```

Similarly for the other listener.

I'd also suggest you get rid of the XHTML transitional DOCTYPE, clearly you aren't transitioning to XHTML (it's been 12 years since XHTML 1.0 and very, very few web sites serve documents as XML, regardless of the DOCTYPE), just use `DOCTYPE html`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful tip, i was actually not able to get this code to work when i first got it and had to change it to point towards my form name. Now when you have given me something useful, i tried it and it is working. Thanks again. Also the DOCTYPE thing is really useful info (i use dreamweaver and when a file is created it is there by default, but now cz of you i know the difference and can make changes that matters).

Comment: Rob can you please help me in achieving this goal ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand all of your code, but let me see if I understand your problem:

You have a form that you want users to select a number of devices from a drop down box.  After the user selects a number, you want a corresponding number of form elements to be populated.

Why don't you merge some of your code in your fiddle with [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mbeasley183/HM4zC/).

Comment: Thnx for trying to understand my problem. Yes you are right about it and good news is that i have got the answer here and it's working. To be more precise abt. what i wanted to do is : If a user selects 6 from a dropmenu, it should populate 6 set of dropdowns (01 set = 3 dropdowns and 1 input field ).